# Revoking blob URL after Creating it in a single line JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, blob, one-liner

I am simply curious about how to do this differently. Right now I have created a single line of code that has **NO** semicolons or new lines. I want to make it clear that this has no errors at all whatsoever. The code creates an HTML blob made of `<h1>Example</h1>`. This is wrapped in a promise so I can access the result. Once I have the result, I use the `&&` operator to avoid semicolons. The blob url is opened immediately and then is revoked after 2000 milliseconds. If you have a solution to make this shorter or done differently without `;` or new lines, please inform me :)

```js
new Promise(r=>r(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'})))).then(u=>{window.open(u)&&setTimeout(t=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u)),2000})
```

I want to make this clear that this is about syntax.

#### Edit:

It turns out that thanks to @Bergi that this is easily possible with an IIFE. Using an IIFE, kind of makes you think backwards. I made some edits. This function works by:

- Creating a HTML Blob URL for `<h1>Example</h1>`
- It runs the URL through an IIFE that does two things

  - Open the URL
  - Set an Event Listener for the window to load, then revoke the URL

```js
((u,e=open(u))=>e.onload=_=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u))(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'})))
```

#### Edit (No need for `e`):

```
(u=>open(u).onload=_=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u))(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'})))
```

Comment: We don't do code-golf in here, but `2e3` shaves one byte, and `window.`  can be discarded

Comment: Actually why the Promise at all? Everything until the `.then` in here is synchronous...

Comment: @Kaiido, `.then` is only applicable for a promise. It is the only way that I know how to do it in a one-liner of code. If you know another way, please make an answer to let me know below.

Comment: And why do you need it to be a one-liner? If it's not for code-golf, then make readable. If you are worried about data-size, pass it to a minifier before deployment.

Comment: I would just like it to be a one-liner because I am in a `one-liner` phase I guess.

Comment: I might try posting this on the code-golf website, they are kinder of better with this type of stuff.

Comment: Yes, you can try there, once again, this is not really a "specific programming problem", it's merely a "code-style" issue and that is not on-topic for SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I am going to delete the question :)

Comment: Thanks, Ps: a not-one-liner in 131B that doesn't pollute the global scope: `{const u=URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'}));open(u);setTimeout(_=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u),2e3)}`

Comment: @myjobistobehappy Notice that using `;` lets you write better one-liners than `&&`.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for helping me out. Let me know how you like what I did :)

Comment: No, I don't like abusing default parameter initialisers as poor man's variable declarations. If you wanted to use that style you'd have used the same for `u`. The application of the [IIFE technique to introduce named variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Named_constants) would have led to `(u=>(e=>e.onload=…)(open(u)))(…)`. However, since you're using `e` only once, why not just write `open(u).onload=…`?

Comment: @Bergi, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason to use a promise when all you need is an [IIFE to introduce variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Named_constants):

```
(u => (
  window.open(u),
  setTimeout(_ =>
    URL.revokeObjectURL(u))
  , 2000)
))(URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'})
))
```

<sub>(Sorry for the readable formatting. Drop whitespaces as you see fit.)</sub>